# Singular wing functionality

Tags: science-based, creature-design, evolution, fauna, alternate-reality

Trying to conceptualize a character,
key features are; bipedalism and one wing instead of two.

The singular wing is evolved and thus must serve a purpose worthy of losing another wing or maybe having two wings brings too much problems.

Now, what situation would favor the evolution of a creature with only one wing?

Comment: Brake a fall, like maple or pine seeds ? Construct a cool setting for it, like balconies along canyon walls ... and say goodbye to symmetry :-)

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Mobula Rays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobula) - they are manta rays that can propel themselves out of the water and 'flap' their single surface bodies, flying at 2m altitudes (although not for long).

[image: A flying Mobula Ray]

Although not great flyers their bodies are optimised for both water and air, so prefer flexing a single body rather than 2 separate 'wings'.

This can be a model for a more successful 'flyer'.

Comment: Unfortunately, -1.  Those are left and right pectoral fins --- not a single wing (or fin). Nice try though!

Answer (score 1):

## Fencing

Many fencing masters of centuries past suggested using a cloak as a secondary weapon while fighting. The first one I think of is Giacomo Di Grassi, who published a treatise on fencing in the 16th century. [You can find more about it here](https://www.wiktenauer.com/wiki/Giacomo_di_Grassi). Unfortunately the links in the content table do not work unless you have expanded the sessions before. Anyway, here is an image you can find there:

[image: A drawing of two fencers, each with a cloak wrapped around their left forearm]

He also says:

> That I may continue in the weapons which are most usual and most commonly worn: After the Dagger, I come to the Cloak: The use whereof was first found by chance and reduced into Art. (...) Wherefore, as men in diverse accidents have casually proved, that the Cloak helps greatly (for as much as they are to wear it daily) they have devised how they may behave themselves in that, in which the Cloak may serve their turn.

[And here is a video demonstrating some concepts of the usage of a cloak during a fight.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oQ88cuzsyqE)

Your creature may therefore have one wing limb serving as a cloak, and [another serve as a piercing or slashing weapon such as the arm of a 1-2-3-death](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E_mbnXJh2Dk&t=63).

As to how it evolved: initially the creature may have had wings like those of a [microraptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microraptor), which had claws capable of tearing flesh. The creature lost the feathers on one wing so as to make strikes with that limb faster, while keeping feathers on the other wing so as to use it as a fencing cloak.

Which limb has feathers and which one doesn't may either be defined directly by genes (such as human handedness and sex) or by some factor while the creature is in its egg (such as the sex of turtles) (and this is still influenced by genes). Alternatively, the creature is born with feathers in both wings, and they pluck one of its own wings as an adult on a regular basis; one of the arms will have feathers that are easier to pluck without harm.

A million years from now, the [farfetch'd](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Farfetch%27d_(Pok%C3%A9mon)) may end up evolving such traits due to convergent evolution.

Comment: I like the direction of this answer. For a real world analogue, consider the fiddler crab: one tiny claw and one whopping huge claw. Similarly, the creatures the OP's people evolved from could have evolved a very large wing (either as a mating attractant or as a weapon) while the other atrophied, either to very small proportions or perhaps disappeared altogether, or perhaps simply got caught up in the musculature of the huge surviving wing.

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work. There is no way for a trait to pass on this way. You see, a physical change of a creature doesn't change its genetics. Which a change in genetics is required for this to work. The problem is here that even if they kept removing their wing, unless some unknown factor changed their genetics, their kids wouldn't lose the wing

Comment: And before you say that evolution works, it doesn't, all evidence points *against* evolution, not towards it. Convergent evolution has never been proved, only hypothesized

Comment: @Firestryke you are cpnfusing cause and effrct. I propose that genetics facilitate plucking, not that plucking changes genetics. As for evolution not working: ok creationist.

Comment: fair point on the first one, except, what causes this change in genetics? Some outside source? You still haven't explained this or how it causes plucking. As for you calling me a creationist, yes I am a creationist, but I will avoid that monster debate as it would be inappropriate on the SE as it's highly controversal

Answer (score 1):

It's probably going to be used for thermoregulation, like a giant fan. It would flap back and forth to disturb the air, and cool down the body, which would work, especially on a hot planet. It would not allow flight, but it will allow for keeping at a comfortable temperature. And, it increases surface area, and thus, the rate of excess heat being shed.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the wing to be in the position of a cape. When still, it looks like a great cape, when flying, it's like a wing on the character's back, each flap gracefully following the wind.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1cAE.jpg) is an animation I made to give you a vision at what I'm getting at:

[image]

Can't resist but to add another version of it: https://media.giphy.com/media/Q095vNkV4RmUyViWSG/giphy.gif

Comment: Could it actually fly with one wing only?

Comment: @Cirfi Yes. Imagine a strong eagle-like flapping motion.

Comment: This is a [tag:science-based] question. This answer is not science-based; it is opinion. _Imagine a strong eagle-like flapping motion._ --> Eagles have two wings; describing (in a comment!) that flight is possible with one wing because eagles can fly is not accurate.

Comment: @Frostfyre I've edited to clarify :)